# 16.04 GUI alert for available updates

Tags: 16.04, updates, update-manager

I'm setting up Ubuntu for a non-tech person to use.  Of course the system is great and user friendly enough for anyone to carry out most basic tasks (internet browsing word processing etc).  However, there seems no GUI alert for available updates.  This seems like something that's rather necessary for a non-technical user.  Is there a way to enable alerts for updates on the system?

Comment: The `Software Updater` is a standard part of Ubuntu. It provides a GUI interface, and regular update notifications. It can be started manually from the Unity dashboard. The `Software & Updates` application is used to custom-tailor how it works. The Software Updater appears without user interaction to notify of pending updates. My 84yo mother loves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup those options from *(Unity) System settings -> Software & Updates*. There you can adjust your preferred updating behaviour.

You can configure your system to search for updates every day, every two days, every week... Then you can adjust what should be done if any updates were found. *It also offers independent behaviour for security and normal updates.*

[image: Update behaviour]

Also you can configure automatic updates too *(maybe off-topic)*, check this two links [Link1](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html) [Link2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) on Ubuntu wiki.

Hope it helps.